# AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights query using Regex does not extract columns for MySql Slow Query Logs

Tags: regex, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

When I run the following query in AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights I get blank output

```
parse @message /Query_time: (?<Query_time>[0-9](\.[0-9]+)?), Lock_time: (?<Lock_time>[0-9](\.[0-9]+)?), (?<Query>(?<=\;)(.*?)(?=\;))/
```

[image]

but if I run it each colume individualy it does extract the values

```
parse @message /Query_time: (?<Query_time>[0-9](\.[0-9]+)?)/
```

[image]

```
# User@Host: ****[****] @ localhost [] Id: 10
# Query_time: 0.000283 Lock_time: 0.000075 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1589784518; SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'TIME_SINCE_ZERO_CONNECTIONS';
```

Is there something I am missing

Comment: Are you sure the lookbehind works? Perhaps try `Query_time: (?<Query_time>[0-9](\.[0-9]+)?), Lock_time: (?<Lock_time>[0-9](\.[0-9]+)?), ;(?<Query>[^;]*);`

Comment: Try `Query_time: (?<Query_time>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?) Lock_time: (?<Lock_time>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)[\s\S]*?;\s*(?<Query>[^;]*)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I tried you suggestion it did not work still showing blank

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried your suggestion also it still showing blank. But as mentined inividually each of the cloumns are showing

Comment: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/sLpuen/2), my regex works with the string you shared. I have just replaced spaces with `\s*` in this demo

Comment: yes you are right and mine works too but as you can see in the screen shot when running it is cloudwatch log in Log Insights it does not work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  yes working now thanks. can you please add as answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
Query_time:\s*(?<Query_time>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*Lock_time:\s*(?<Lock_time>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)[\s\S]*?;\s*(?<Query>[^;]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sLpuen/2). Details:

- `Query_time:` - literal string
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<Query_time>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)` - Group "Query_time": a float or int like number
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces
- `Lock_time:` - literal string
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<Lock_time>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)`  - Group "Lock_time": a float or int like number
- `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars including line break chars, as few as possible
- `;` -  a semi-colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<Query>[^;]*)` - Group "Query": any 0 or more chars other than `;`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's mine, which extracts all the fields:

```
# fields @message |
parse @message /# Time:\s(?<Time>.*?)\sUser@Host: (?<User>.*)\[.*?\]\s@ \s.(?<Host>.*?). Id: \d*\s# Query_time: (?<Query_time>.*?)\s Lock_time: (?<Lock_time>.*?)\sRows_sent: (?<Rows_sent>.*?)\sRows_examined: (?<Rows_examined>.*?)\s(?<Query>.*)/ 
| sort Query_time desc
```